# Convert data format for R package Mfuzz

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf` containing 4 different columns. I want to convert this to a format that is accepted by [`Mfuzz` package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Mfuzz.html) to generate cluster. I want to see the cluster of `sample1`, `sample2` and `sample3`. How do I convert mydf to a format used in `Mfuzz`?

```
mydf

    s. no  sample1  sample2 sample3
    1        0.003   0.9       11.3
    2        0.003   1.9       33.3 
    3        0.004   2.9       3.4   
    4        0.005   2.0       44.4
    5        0.004   2.3       43.4
```

Comment: You can check [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biobase/inst/doc/ExpressionSetIntroduction.pdf) to convert to ExpressionSet class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this little example is helpful

```
set.seed(42)
mydf = data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=runif(10),C=rpois(10,l=1))
test = new('ExpressionSet', exprs=mydf) # fails
test = new('ExpressionSet', exprs=as.matrix(mydf)) # works
t.cl = mfuzz(test,c=3,m=1.25)
mfuzz.plot(set,cl=t.cl, mfrow=c(2,2))
```